How to Efficiently Manage State in Flutter for Dynamic Forms with Conditional Logic?
I'm building a Flutter application where I need to create dynamic forms that change based on user input. For example, certain fields should become visible or required based on the selections in previous fields. I've looked into various state management solutions like Provider, Bloc, and Riverpod, but I'm unsure how to implement this efficiently, especially with the need to preserve form state and validate dynamically.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
A form starts with a dropdown menu (DropdownButtonFormField), and depending on the user's choice, a new set of fields appears.
Each new field can itself conditionally trigger more fields.
The state of all fields, shown and hidden, needs to be preserved until the form is submitted.
I've started with a simple implementation using Bloc, but I'm facing issues with updating the state reactively without rebuilding the entire form, which causes input losses and poor user experience.
I started by implementing the form using the Bloc state management approach. My goal was to manage the visibility and validation state of various form fields based on user input from preceding fields. Specifically, I used a Bloc to react to state changes such as selection in a dropdown menu.
I expected that when a user selects an option from the dropdown, only the relevant sections of the form would update, adding or removing fields without affecting the data already entered in other parts of the form. The idea was to have a seamless user experience where fields could appear and disappear dynamically based on inputs, without causing disruptions to other form inputs.
